# How can I assign an Elastic IP to one of the balanced instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2

If you have one instance, and auto scaling needs to create one more, then you have two instances. But when auto scaling wants to remove one because it's not needed, the new or the old one can be removed.

So, the instance I had with the Elastic IP now it's removed ...

How can I apply a Elastic IP always to one of the instances of a auto scaling activity ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hmm.. You could have a small code that checks if the ip is available, and will attached to one of your instance. You can write it such as when the instance is launch it automatically attached that Elastic IP to itself if that IP is available.

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2x scaling groups as described [here](http://shlomoswidler.com/2011/01/aws-auto-scaling-and-elb-with-reliable-root-domain-handling.html).